# Wrap/Cast class and struct with same data c++ to implement external api

Tags: c++, class, struct, enums, wrapper

I'm trying to bring the functionality of an external lib to a framework.
The external lib has a struct which uses its own vector struct but the framework has its own vector class.

How I wrap an external lib to work with the framework?
I need to use a feature of the lib but the user must not interact with the lib source himself.

```
// External Lib
namespace Lib
{
    struct vec2
    {
        float x, y;

        // Functions
        // ....
    }

    enum ObjectType
    {
        type0,
        type1
    };

    struct Object
    {
        /// This constructor sets the body definition default values.
        Object()
        {
            type = type0;
            position.set(0.0f, 0.0f);
            angle = 0.0f;
            active = true;
            userData = NULL;
        }

        ObjectType type;
        vec2 position;
        float32 angle;
        bool active;
        void* userData;
    };

    // The feature I need to use
    void CreateObject(const Object* obj);
}

// The Framework
namespace Framework
{
    class Vector2
    {
        f32 x, y;

        // Functions ....
    }

    // In order to use CreateObject from the external lib:

    // How to wrap the enum ObjectType to the 
    // enum class standard here?
    // Eg.:
    enum class MyObjectType
    {
        k_type0 = Lib::type0,
        k_type1 = Lib::type1
    };

    // How to wrap struct Object from the external lib
    // Eg.:
    struct MyObject
    {
        /// This constructor sets the body definition default values.
        MyObject()
        {
            type = MyObjectType::k_type0;
            position = Vector2::k_zero;
            angle = 0.0f;
            active = true;
            userData = nullptr;
        }


        MyObjectType type;
        Vector2 position;
        f32 angle;
        bool active;
        void* userData;
    };

    // How to create the object?
    // I have no idea from here besides manually copy
    void MyCreateObject(const MyObject* obj)
    {
        Lib::Object libObj;
        libObj.type = obj.type;
        libObj.angle = obj.angle;

        Lib::CreateObject(&libObj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. First, think how to hide the declarations of lib from the user. User might only use your header file. So, do not expose them through header file. Use the header or declaration of lib in your cpp files only.

However, sometimes declaration of lib might creep into your framework. This will be prominent in poor design. It requires diligent effort in the designing to create separation of interfaces and implementation so that they can be changed independently.

Comment: I have no issues with including. My main concern is wheter there is a better way to do it since there a lot of similar situations like this across the lib and I will need manually rewrite each one.